# Lambda expression classes in GraalVM reflection configuration

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm, jdbi, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to run [JDBI](https://jdbi.org/) library in Quarkus native mode. By including all classes that are accessed via reflection to [reflection-config.json](https://gist.github.com/Eng-Fouad/7b5925481dd391fcc74487a68484b987), I was able to run it successfully.

However, I still got this exception (as warning) at runtime upon calling:

```
Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create(agroalDataSource).installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());
```

```
2022-07-18 09:33:32,935 [] WARNING [com.git.ben.caf.cac.LocalLoadingCache] (main) Cannot determine if CacheLoader can bulk load: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.CachingSqlParser$$Lambda$1a0f8d592d890e8f26473320a5cdb05c88cf7099.loadAll(java.lang.Iterable)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(DynamicHub.java:2227)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.hasLoadAll(LocalLoadingCache.java:182)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.newBulkMappingFunction(LocalLoadingCache.java:160)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3761)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.build(Caffeine.java:1104)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.CachingSqlParser.<init>(CachingSqlParser.java:30)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.CachingSqlParser.<init>(CachingSqlParser.java:25)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ColonPrefixSqlParser.<init>(ColonPrefixSqlParser.java:41)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatements.<init>(SqlStatements.java:53)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at com.oracle.svm.methodhandles.Util_java_lang_invoke_MethodHandle.invokeInternal(Target_java_lang_invoke_MethodHandle.java:205)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeBasic(MethodHandle.java:76)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeBasic(MethodHandle.java:0)
        at java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.invokeExact_MT(Invokers$Holder)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.config.ConfigRegistry.lambda$configFactory$3(ConfigRegistry.java:100)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.exceptions.Unchecked.lambda$function$4(Unchecked.java:76)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.config.ConfigRegistry.get(ConfigRegistry.java:78)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.config.ConfigRegistry.<init>(ConfigRegistry.java:47)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.<init>(Jdbi.java:58)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.create(Jdbi.java:109)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.create(Jdbi.java:93)
```

I tried adding the lambda expression class to `reflection-config.json` but that didn't solve it:

```
  {
    "name" : "org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.CachingSqlParser$$Lambda$1a0f8d592d890e8f26473320a5cdb05c88cf7099",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true,
    "queryAllDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "queryAllPublicConstructors" : true,
    "queryAllDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "queryAllPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
    "allPublicClasses" : true
  }
```

I got this warning message at generating native image:

```
Warning: Could not resolve org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.CachingSqlParser$$Lambda$1a0f8d592d890e8f26473320a5cdb05c88cf7099 for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.CachingSqlParser$$Lambda$1a0f8d592d890e8f26473320a5cdb05c88cf7099.
```

How to include lambda expression classes into [`reflection-config`](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Reflection.md)?

Comment: If this hidden class has been generated for a lambda expression, an existing `loadAll` method must be declared by a functional interface. Then, the first thing to try, is to ensure that the interface and its method are included. What’s irritating, is that the caller is named `hasLoadAll`, which suggests that it is actually expected that the method could be absent.

Comment: @Holger `loadAll` is a default method in the functional interface [`CacheLoader`](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/05a040c2478341bab8a58a02b3dc1fe14d626d72/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CacheLoader.java#L86). Can `Class#getMethod` [in here](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/05a040c2478341bab8a58a02b3dc1fe14d626d72/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/LocalLoadingCache.java#L182) throw `NoSuchMethodException` as the lambda expression class did not override `loadAll`?

Comment: @Holger and [here](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/d8b13aaec130d8086b083ef06db8f50ede817766/core/src/main/java/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/CachingSqlParser.java#L30) is where the lambda expression is created.

Comment: Normally, `getMethod` will find an inherited method if no overriding method exists. But your environment isn’t the normal one. But note that besides warning, the `hasLoadAll` method does the right thing, i.e. `return false;` after encountering the `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: It might be a case of the classes being initialized at build time causing the problem. Check out https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/native-image/ClassInitialization/#specifying-class-initialization-explicitly

Comment: GraalVM team replied to me on Slack: "Currently, that feature is not supported. There is a good chance that it would be implemented in a few months, but it is not available yet."

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is no workaround at the moment. Config files has all the classes that should be reflectively called, but since lambda names are not stable in Java, we cannot have even a clue on which lambda reflection would be called. Native-Image needs to know all the reachable types at build time, and we need stable names or some other approach to make this possible. We are aware of the problem, and there are intentions for it to be solved, I just don't know when yet."

Comment: As workaround to omit the warning, I added this line into `application.properties`: `quarkus.log.category."com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache".level=ERROR`

Comment: https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/2071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple. The default method `CacheLoader.loadAll` has to be included into `reflection-config.json`:

```
{"name":"com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.CacheLoader","methods":[{"name":"loadAll","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Iterable"]}]}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing! So, now you can run JDBI v3 in Quarkus?

Comment: @SlavaMedvediev Yes. Here is a sample project: https://github.com/Eng-Fouad/jdbi-quarkus-native

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort putting things together!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, reflection on lambda classes is not supported on Native Image. Configuration files expect the fully qualified name of the class that should be registered for reflection, serialization, etc. Lambda classes in the JDK don't have stable names, so we cannot store them in those files. We are aware of the problem, and we have in plan to fix it. I will let you know here as soon as it is done.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no workaround at the moment for what you need. The main problem is that on Native Image, we have a closed world principle, and all the types used at runtime must be known at build time. Therefore, all the lambdas will be created at build time. But since lambda names are unstable, at build time we don't have the same name as it would be in the `reflection-config.json` and we cannot write down lambdas in the configuration file.